# Error installing SQLite ADO.NET on Win 7

Tags: sqlite, windows-7, ado.net

I am getting the following error when I try to install the ADO.NET version of SQLite on two different Win 7 laptops:

```
Installer.exe: #32 @ 2012.05.06T13:58:34.8921292: Configuration.Process: No actual changes will be made to this system because "what-if" mode is enabled.
Installer.exe: #33 @ 2012.05.06T13:58:34.8951293: TraceOps.ShowMessage: Cannot continue, the "confirm" option is not enabled.
```

I am running the Installer.exe as administrator.

Answer (score 21):

Well I am having exactly the same problem,

but the issue is b/c Installer.exe requires a command line argument, called "-confirm"

They made this to make the exe not install when just double clicked.

So pls try following command from command line

```
Installer -confirm true
```

Source : http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/ci/793e9b039d165c768114c4c646c9ee1b2e44e03d

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It turns out I was going down a rabbit hole.

SQLite doesn't need to be installed.  I tripped over the answer here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q8